# Laravel select username by custom ID

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I trying to get user username by custom ID.

Example: user "romas56" get table row with called "steam_id".

I'm trying to take out username by SteamID like that:

```
$match->MVPusername = User::select('username')->where('steam_id', '=', $match->MVP)->get();
```

Everythings works fine, but i'm getting username like that:

```
[{"username":"romas56"}]
```

I need to get just: romas56 without `[{"username":""}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search first, then select `username` property. Optional is used to avoid `trying to get property of non object` error when no user with `steam_id` is found

```
optional(User::where('steam_id', '=', $match->MVP)->first())->username;
```

Comment: Working like a charm! Really thanks for fast answer and trying me to understand laravel!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the column in `[]` this, 
also if you go check equal to then no need to `=`

```
User::where('steam_id',$match->MVP)->first(['username']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```php
$username = User::where('steam_id', $match->MVP)->first()->value('username');
```